# Jhipster registry try to register itself

Tags: java, cloud, registry, config, jhipster

I am using release package of Jhipster Registry v7.1.0

It's trying to connect itself at startup and throws exception

```
2021-10-09 22:17:45.578  WARN 1768 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2021-10-09 22:17:45.578  INFO 1768 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_JHIPSTER-REGISTRY/jhipsterRegistry:73fc39b9052cc9c8bdea1a67d1e92d17 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 10 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:441)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:283)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:66)
```

Arguments that I use to start it

```
--spring.security.user.password=admin
--server.port=8761
--spring.profiles.active=prod
--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.type=native
--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.search-locations=file:./configuration
```

and application.yaml in configuration file is like that:

```
configserver:
  name: JHipster Registry config server
  status: Connected to the JHipster Registry config server

    jhipster:
      security:
        authentication:
          jwt:
            secret: ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SnpkV0lpT2lJeE1qTTBOVFkzT0Rrd0lpd2libUZ0WlNJNklrcHZhRzRnUkc5bElpd2lhV0YwSWpveE5URTJNak01TURJeWZRLmNUaElJb0R2d2R1ZVFCNDY4SzV4RGM1NjMzc2VFRm9xd3hqRl94U0p5UVE
```